# iOS: Reset constraints programmatically from storyboard to adjust frame change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Using storyboard, I've set up multiple views encompassed by a scroll view like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg8Ux.png)

Everything under the "More Symptoms" button is a view (except the Collection View *behind* it). Let's call it `moreSymptomsView`. Now what I'm trying to do is when the More Symptoms button is tapped, I'd like to shift `moreSymptomsView` down with `setFrame` and reveal the collection view behind it by setting the `hidden` property to false.

It functions properly, but after trying to scroll, the `moreSymptomsView` goes back up to its original place like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Plr.png) (I'm assuming due to it's constraints).

How should I go about resetting the constraints of `moreSymptomsView` to the bottom of the new collection view programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want change frame when using `AutoLayout`. You should change `constant` of `Constraint`. If you `setFrame` It will auto back to previous state if have interaction with UI. With your case you can do like this:

1. Drag drop top constraint of `More Symptoms`:

[image]

name for it. I named it to `constraintTopSympotomsLabel`

2. When you want change frame it:

   `self.constraintTopSympotomsLabel.constant = ValueYouWant`

for moving it to new frame.

You can change all of constraints with the same way to achieve frame you want.

Hope this help!

Comment: This is definitely a solid approach, it's similar to other answers I've seen involving this issue. I used a similar concept and made it work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that sees this question in the future, here's what I did to solve this issue:

```
- (IBAction)showMoreSymptoms:(id)sender {

if(!moreSymptomsExpanded) {
    moreSymptomsExpanded = true;
    [_moreSymptomsCollectionView setHidden:false];
    [_moreSymptomsButton setTitle:@"Less Symptoms" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //change frames
    [_moreSymptomsView setFrame:CGRectMake(_moreSymptomsView.frame.origin.x, _moreSymptomsView.frame.origin.y+_moreSymptomsCollectionView.frame.size.height, _moreSymptomsView.frame.size.width, _moreSymptomsView.frame.size.height)];

    //change constraint to the bottom of the new collection view
    _higherPriorityMoreSymptomsViewConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_moreSymptomsView
                                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                toItem:_moreSymptomsCollectionView
                                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                            multiplier:1
                                                                              constant:1];
    _higherPriorityMoreSymptomsViewConstraint.priority = 1000;
    [_moreSymptomsView.superview addConstraint:_higherPriorityMoreSymptomsViewConstraint];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
} else {
    moreSymptomsExpanded = false;
    [_moreSymptomsCollectionView setHidden:true];
    [_moreSymptomsButton setTitle:@"More Symptoms" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //reset frames back
    [_moreSymptomsView setFrame:CGRectMake(_moreSymptomsView.frame.origin.x, _moreSymptomsView.frame.origin.y-_moreSymptomsCollectionView.frame.size.height, _moreSymptomsView.frame.size.width, _moreSymptomsView.frame.size.height)];

    //reset back to original constraint
    [_moreSymptomsView.superview removeConstraint:_higherPriorityMoreSymptomsViewConstraint];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

}

1. I set the original top constraint's priority on storyboard to a lower priority (750).
2. When the `moreSymptomsButton` is tapped, I shifted the frame of the `moreSymptomsView` down as expected
3. I created a new top constraint called `higherPriorityMoreSymptomsViewConstraint` and set the `toItem` attribute to the new collection view that I'm showing (`moreSymptomsCollectionView`) with a higher priority
4. To collapse back to the original state, reset the frame and remove the constraint created earlier.

For more of an explanation, check this [link](http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/restoring-nslayoutconstraints-after-a-change/) out

Comment: Great, It is better than my solution. Thank you.